# Using Google Big Query to Organise an Edgelist for Spreadsheet Use

Tags: sql, excel, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble trying to reorganise a large edgelist I have exported as .csv from Gephi.

The structure of the data is:

- Two columns, "Source" and "Target".
- "Source" contains user IDs and Target contains demographic information such as city, country, and university.
- Due to the structure of the data, a user may be duplicated in "Source" if they have multiple demographic records.

For example:

```
Source      Target

user142     cityA

user532     countryA

user352     cityC

user532     cityA

user143     countryC

user532     university1
```

My desired output is for each unique user to be positioned on their own row, with  separate columns for "City", "Country", and "University" - like this:

```
Unique User    City     Country     University

user142        CityA

user532        CityA    CountryA    University1

user352        CityC

user143                 CountryC
```

I've been able to separate the edgelist into the desired output in Excel using a number of steps using the following index, match, and array formulae. However this is lengthy, and Excel often crashes when large edgelists are involved.

**Excel Process:**

**Step 1:**

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5819, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:$D1, $A$2:$A$5819), 0))
```

This filters all the users for unique records (colA) and places them in a new column (colD).

**Step 2:**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$174, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D2:D2,$B$2:$B$174)+IF($A$2:$A$174<>$D2, 1, 0), 0)), 0))
```

This looks down the "Target" column (B), against the unique users in the column created in step 1 (colD). This does not order the output across columns, however. So left to right may read city, country, university, or country, university, city, etc for each unique user.

**Step 3:**

```
=transpose(sort(transpose(E2:H2)))
```

This step then orders the output alphabetically across columns, so the left-right columns read city, country, university.

**My main problem is that this is a slow and manual process, so I'm looking to utilise SQL in Big Query to make this flow as efficient as possible.**

Any information on how to begin structuring a Query to sort the data into the desired output would be highly appreciated.

I already have some experience with SQL, however this has been mainly in terms of text extraction and regex.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know what is the city, the country, and the university?

Comment: Hi Gordon - the data is arranged so that each city/country/university has a unique identifier. cities are prefixed "ci", countries as "co" etc, with a following unique number.

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, you could do this with conditional aggregation.  It would look something like this:

```
select source,
       max(case when type = 'City' then target end) as city,
       max(case when type = 'Country' then target end) as country,
       max(case when type = 'University' then target end) as university
from demographics d
group by source;
```

Your question doesn't specify a column like `type`.  But it seems that you need one if you have different types of information.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this works brilliantly - thank you! I do have one question on the function.. If there are multiple cities given per unique user, is there a way to output these into their own columns? Thus the columns may read 'City 1', 'City 2' etc.

Comment: @Luke . . . You can use `array_agg()` to put them into an array.

Comment: @Luke Hi Luke, welcome to Stackoverflow! If Gordon's answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer as this is important in this forum: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon commented, you can use [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) to aggregate all these information together. Example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Source,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Target, r'^ci'), Target, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) City,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Target, r'^co'), Target, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) Country,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Target, r'^uni'), Target, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) Universiry
FROM
  `your_table`
GROUP BY
  Source
```

Working with simulated data:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 'user142' AS Source, 'cityA' AS Target UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user532', 'countryA' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user 352', 'cityC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user532', 'cityA' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user143', 'countryC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user532', 'university1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user532', 'cityB'
)

SELECT
  Source,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Target, r'^ci'), Target, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) City,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Target, r'^co'), Target, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) Country,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Target, r'^uni'), Target, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) Universiry
FROM
  data
GROUP BY
  Source
```

Comment: Hi Willian - really appreciate the layout of your examples here. I gave it a go and everything seems to be working. In order to export my results for spreadsheet use I downloaded the query results in json format, coverted it to .csv which then unested the multiple city entries into their own columns (e.g city_001, city_002) which is just what I was looking for! There may be a way to do this anyway within Big Query, however I'm quite happy with the result.